# Как запустить крон Node.js скрипта?

Tags: linux, node.js, сервер, хостинг, cron

Мой сайт находится на хостинге. Для серверной части использую Node.js. Node.js приложение находится по пути `/home/userName/api`. Мне нужно запустить крон на выполнение Node.js скрипта. Скрипт находится в `/home/userName/api/crons/changeTariff.js`. Для теста в этом скрипте пока находится следующий код.

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFileSync("changeTariffLogTest.txt", JSON.stringify({"date": new Date()}));
```

Какую команду в настройке крона в CPanel нужно написать?
[image: Скриншот настройки крона в CPanel]

Интересует именно команда, как настроить время я знаю. Я так понимаю, что недостаточно написать команду в этой сроке. Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее как мне запустить этот крон. Все инструкции, которые я находил, были для PHP. Хостеры тоже знают только как настроить крон на PHP скрипт.

Comment: `/usr/bin/node /path/to/script.js` не она?

Comment: А что кроме команды надо то? в обычном crontab еще имя пользователя от которого запускать.

Comment: Так, не работает. Я не знаю что кроме команды нужно. Тех поддержка хостинга говорит, что нужно что-то еще в коде прописывать, а что именно - они не знают. Пока что получилось запустить крон командой `wget -O - -q -t 1 site.com/change-tariff`. В маршруте /change-tariff написал код из файла `changeTariff.js`. Но мне этот способ не нравится, это костыль.

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что крон должен запускаться как-то так, как вы написали, и я пробовал разные варианты, похожие на ваш, но это не работает. Странно, что тех. поддержка не знает как это решить, хотя хостинг далеко не самый плохой, и они всегда хорошо выполняли свою работу, кроме этого случая и еще одного.

Comment: если на сервер можно зайти по ssh то я бы не стал выдумывать костыли и использовать панели, а просто добавил бы задачу в крон: `cron -e` и `1 */1 * * * (/usr/bin/node /home/userName/api/crons/changeTariff.js)`

Comment: Может быть, вы запускаете node не из той папки, которой ожидаете? Попробуйте запустить скрипт **без cron** находясь в разных папках, например, `cd /tmp && /usr/bin/node /home/userName/api/crons/changeTariff.js` посмотрите, правильно ли все запускается и работает?